# Unable to catch the exception in Activity Worker Class

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-swf

I have some activities and they can throw some custom exception. The problem is that i am unable to catch the thrown exception in the Activity Worker class and the stack trace is being displayed. I tried to catch the Throwable but not useful as stack trace is again getting displayed.

**Activities Implementation Class**

```
public class TestActivitiesImpl implements TestActivities{

    @Override
    public Integer testAct1() {
        System.out.println("Activity 1 ---->Start");
        int count = 0;
        while(count < 1000){
            count ++;
        }
        return 1;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Override
    public Integer testAct2() throws MyException {
        System.out.println("Activity 2 ---->Start");
        if(true){
            throw new MyException("Failed to execute the activity");
        }
        return 1;
    }
}
```

**Activities Worker Class**

```
public class TestActivitiesWorker {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            ClientConfiguration config = new ClientConfiguration().withSocketTimeout(70*1000);

            String swfAccessId = "ABCDXYZ";
            String swfSecretKey = "ABCDXYZ";
            AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(swfAccessId, swfSecretKey);

            AmazonSimpleWorkflow service = new AmazonSimpleWorkflowClient(awsCredentials, config);
            service.setEndpoint("ABCDXYZ");

            String domain = "EC2-TEST";

            ActivityWorker aw = new ActivityWorker(service, domain, "TestList");
            aw.addActivitiesImplementation(new TestActivitiesImpl());
            aw.start();

        }catch (Throwable e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to execute Job");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**Stack trace**

Oct 18, 2014 2:02:53 PM

```
com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.worker.SynchronousActivityTaskPoller execute
    SEVERE: Failure processing activity task with taskId=12, workflowGenerationId=AsyncTest, activity={Name: TestActivities.testAct2,Version: 1.2}, activityInstanceId=2
    com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.ActivityFailureException: Failed to execute the activity : ["com.myapp.test.MyException",{"cause":null,"stackTrace":[{"methodName":"testAct2","fileName":"TestActivitiesImpl.java","lineNumber":20,"className":"com.myapp.test.TestActivitiesImpl","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"invoke0","fileName":"NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java","lineNumber":-2,"className":"sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl","nativeMethod":true},{"methodName":"invoke","fileName":"NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java","lineNumber":57,"className":"sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"invoke","fileName":"DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java","lineNumber":43,"className":"sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"invoke","fileName":"Method.java","lineNumber":606,"className":"java.lang.reflect.Method","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"execute","fileName":"POJOActivityImplementation.java","lineNumber":64,"className":"com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.pojo.POJOActivityImplementation","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"execute","fileName":"ActivityImplementationBase.java","lineNumber":46,"className":"com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.generic.ActivityImplementationBase","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"execute","fileName":"SynchronousActivityTaskPoller.java","lineNumber":196,"className":"com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.worker.SynchronousActivityTaskPoller","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"run","fileName":"ActivityTaskPoller.java","lineNumber":92,"className":"com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.worker.ActivityTaskPoller$2","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"runWorker","fileName":"ThreadPoolExecutor.java","lineNumber":1145,"className":"java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"run","fileName":"ThreadPoolExecutor.java","lineNumber":615,"className":"java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"run","fileName":"Thread.java","lineNumber":724,"className":"java.lang.Thread","nativeMethod":false}],"message":"Failed to execute the activity","localizedMessage":"Failed to execute the activity","suppressed":["[Ljava.lang.Throwable;",[]]}]
    at com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.pojo.POJOActivityImplementation.throwActivityFailureException(POJOActivityImplementation.java:110)
    at com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.pojo.POJOActivityImplementation.execute(POJOActivityImplementation.java:67)
    at com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.generic.ActivityImplementationBase.execute(ActivityImplementationBase.java:46)
    at com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.worker.SynchronousActivityTaskPoller.execute(SynchronousActivityTaskPoller.java:196)
    at com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.worker.ActivityTaskPoller$2.run(ActivityTaskPoller.java:92)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: Could you show the stack trace ?

Comment: Yes, sure.. I have posted the stack trace

Answer (score 1):

It behaves as designed. The activity worker is not expected to fail if an activity implementation method throws an exception. The thrown exception is delivered to the workflow implementation and has to be handled there. It is also visible in the workflow history in the details field of [ActivityTaskFailedEvent](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/apireference/API_ActivityTaskFailedEventAttributes.html).

Comment: Is there any way that the user is not shown any stack trace in the command prompt of activity worker if any of the activity fails? My target is to show custom message to user instead of the stack trace in the activity worker command prompt when any of the activity fails.

Comment: AFAIK it uses Log4J for logging. So you can disable the error logging from that class.

Comment: Is there any way to shutdown all the activity worker and workflow worker from the workflow implementation class. Say, after all my activities are completed then, i want to shut down all the worker.

Comment: Just create an activity that shuts down the workers and invoke it at the end of the workflow.

Comment: thanks for your response...By creating the worker object in an activity like WorkflowWorker wfw = new WorkflowWorker(service, domain, "List"); then wfw.shutDownAndAwait... will work? it will shut down the worker? A code snippet will be really helpful.. thank you in advance

Comment: I don't think it is going to work as you will need another worker to listen to that activity. So you have to create an activity that gets its own worker as a constructor parameter and calls shutdown on it in a separate thread after returning (to complete itself for the calling workflow). What's your use case? If your workflow shuts down the workers, how does it know when to start them?

Comment: My use case is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26181236/iterate-over-the-list-of-activities-based-on-the-input-provided-using-aws-swf/26184230?noredirect=1#comment41324270_26184230 . After the execution of all the commands for a date range I want to shut down all the activities worker and work flow worker. Also, if the any of the activity throws any exception then also i want to shut down all the activities and workflow worker. Next day i will again start the workers and then execute my activities.

Comment: By "I will again start the workers" do you mean that you are going to do it manually once a day? Do you plan to have some process (or cron job) that is going to be executed automatically once a day?

Comment: I am facing some issues for shutting down the workers.Please go through the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26565620/shutdown-activity-worker-and-workflow