# Shutdown activity worker and workflow

Tags: amazon-swf

Is there any way to shutdown activity and workflow worker after all the activities in my workflow implementation have completed its execution or if any of them throws any exception.

Comment: Here is my usecase http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26181236/iterate-over-the-list-of-activities-based-on-the-input-provided-using-aws-swf/26184230?noredirect=1#comment41324270_26184230

Comment: Are you saying you want to have your workflow shutdown any workers that are polling for decisions or activities or that you want to do cleanup at the end of a workflow?

Answer (score 0):

You can have special "shutdown worker" activity type. This activity implementation initiates shutdown of its worker. At the end of the workflow execution you always invoke this activity from doFinally method of [TryCatchFinally](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/flow/core/TryCatchFinally.html) that wraps all other workflow logic.